# Sorting a "Tuple" by the second value (or by sum)

Tags: python, perl

My purpose is to make a subroutine that takes a list of random 4-toops, sorts
then non-destructively by the sum of each toop from largest to smallest, and returns the sorted list.

An example output should be:

```
---- random 4-toops:
toop 1: (93 97 78 77); 345
toop 2: (-1 82 92 -45); 128
toop 3: (62 25 -31 -4); 52
toop 4: (-77 -86 18 36); -109
toop 5: (-72 -96 -83 -6); -257
---- random 4-toops sorted by sum:
toop 1: (93 97 78 77); sum = 345
toop 2: (-1 82 92 -45); sum = 128
toop 3: (62 25 -31 -4); sum = 52
toop 4: (-77 -86 18 36); sum = -109
toop 5: (-72 -96 -83 -6); sum = -257
```

Here my Python variation of the code that is already working:

```
def sort_random_4_toops_by_sum(toops):
    summit = 0
    s = []
    for i in toops:
        summit = 0
        for d in xrange(0,4):
            summit += i[d]
        s.append(summit)
    together = zip(toops, s)
    sortedtog = sorted(together, key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
    toops = [x[0] for x in sortedtog]
    return toops
```

So I am stuck with this problem: In Python, I simply zipped my sum list and my tuples list together, and then sorted by the second element in each tuple, which is always the sum. Is there an equivalent function in perl that can sort according to the second element of a tuple? Here is my attempt so far.

```
sub sort_random_4_toops_by_sum {

    my ( @sorted_toops,@sorted_toops2, @sorted_toops_sums, @sortedtoops3 ) = @_;

    @sorted_toops2 = map { [ $_, sum( @$_ ) ] } @sorted_toops;
    @sorted_toops_sums = reverse sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @sorted_toops2;

    my @sortedtoops3 = map { $_->[0] } @sorted_toops_sums;

    return \@sortedtoops3;
}
```

It is telling me this:

```
Can't locate List/Tuples.pm in @INC
```

The test code to generate the right output:

```perl
sub test_step_3 {

    my $toops = gen_random_4_toops( 1, 100, 5 );

    print "---- random 4-toops:\n";

    my $tn = 1;
    foreach ( @{ sort_random_4_toops_by_sum( @{$toops} ) } ) {
        print "toop $tn:\t(@{$_}); " . sum( @{$_} ) . "\n";
        $tn++;
    }

    print "---- random 4-toops sorted by sum:\n";

    my $sorted_toops = sort_random_4_toops_by_sum( @{$toops} );

    $tn = 1;
    foreach ( @{$sorted_toops} ) {
        print "toop $tn:\t(@{$_}); sum = " . sum( @{$_} ) . "\n";
        $tn++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you're showing can't possibly generate the message you say it does, because it doesn't reference `List::Tuples`. It's also a bit of an unclear mess. Can you please tidy it up and make sure that the code you provide is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: in the Python version, you could simply do `sorted(toops, key = lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got way too much machinery there. Since I can't make a lot of sense of your code, I'm going to work from scratch. I'm also going to assume that your "4-tuples" are just array references of 4 elements each, because that's all they need to be.

```
use List::Util 'sum';

my @tuples = generate_a_bunch_of_random_tuples();

# Zip each tuple with its sum
my @tuples_with_sums = map { [ $_, sum(@$_) ] } @tuples;

my @sorted_with_sums = reverse sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @tuples_with_sums;

my @sorted = map { $_->[0] } @sorted_with_sums;
```

It is, in fact, possible to do the whole thing as a single statement in an instance of the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
my @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
             reverse sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map { [ $_, sum(@$_) ] }
             @tuples;
```

but I wrote it out the long way for the sake of ease of understanding.

A "zip" (which you can get from [List::MoreUtils](http://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)) is only really of use if you already have multiple parallel lists. If every element of the output list depends on one element of a single input list, `map` works just as well — in fact, better.

Comment: I edited my code above, and the output is not printing out Anything except the printed "----- random 4-toops:" and "-----random 4-toops by sum:". I thought I had followed your logic correctly... do I need to change the test case?

Comment: Nevermind, I made a change and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: By just swapping `$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]` to `$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]` you can omit the `reverse`.

Comment: @dgw yes, but it's a lot clearer with `reverse` IMO.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, they're *tupes*. I've never before seen "toop" used to mean a tuple in mathematics or programming

The problem with your own code is that you are copying the parameters of `sort_random_4_toops_by_sum` to the wrong place. You have

```
my @sorted_toops = ();
my ( @sorted_toops2, @sorted_toops_sums, @sortedtoops3 ) = @_;
```

and the code expects the *unsorted* data in the (very badly-named) `@sorted_toops`. You also declare `@sortedtoops3` twice. If you change it as below the your program will work properly

```
sub sort_random_4_toops_by_sum {
    my @sorted_toops = @_;
    my ( @sorted_toops2, @sorted_toops_sums, @sortedtoops3 );

    @sorted_toops2 = map { [ $_, sum( @$_ ) ] } @sorted_toops;
    @sorted_toops_sums = reverse sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @sorted_toops2;

    @sortedtoops3 = map { $_->[0] } @sorted_toops_sums;

    return \@sortedtoops3;
}
```

I suggest that you make use of the [`List::UtilsBy`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy) module, which provides a `rev_nsort_by` (reverse numeric sort by) utility function. Using that, you can reduce your `sort_random_4_toops_by_sum` to just this

```
use List::UtilsBy qw/ rev_nsort_by /;

sub sort_random_4_toops_by_sum {
    [ rev_nsort_by { sum @$_ } @_ ];
}
```